# My c++ program does not appear to evualuate the comparison between a string, and a variable which I have but input into using getline

Tags: c++, string, comparison, cin, getline

I have a string variable called `input` which i use `getline` to input text into. When I try to compare the variable `input` to another string such as `if(input == "new game")` it does not appear to evaluate the comparison. I know that it is actually inputing the correct text because when I use `cout` on `input` it outputs correctly (typing in "new game" will output "new game"). I looked up problems with `getline` and I read that `cin` leaves behind the `\n` in an input string which is picked up by `getline`. I tried using `cin.ignore()`, `cin.clear()`, and `cin.sync()` but they do not appear to fix the issue. Besides, there isn't any input that comes before `getline(cin, input)` anyway. The code in question is blow, any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
int main(){
string input;
while(input != "quit"){
    getline(cin, input);
    if(input == "new game"){
        town(player);
    }
    if(input == "load game"){
        cout << "enter save file: " << endl;
        load(player);
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: [Works here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/agJMrBUOGlVclHjk)

Comment: @chris I ended up using the ``string.find()`` method on input and using ``!=`` to compare it to ``npos`` to evaluate if any part of ``input`` matches the string and it worked. It looks like getline was putting a \n character on the end of ``input``.

Comment: `getline` is specified not to store the delimiter in the string. Either your `getline` is broken or something else is going on.

Comment: Works for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I Foud the error, You forgot to **include string** module in the beginning.
just include string and it will work fine.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;
      int main(){
        string input;
          while(input != "quit"){
            getline(cin, input);
           if(input == "new game"){
             town(player);
         }
           if(input == "load game"){
             cout << "enter save file: " << endl;
             load(player);
         }
      } 
    return 0;
  }
```